# Confirmation alert msg for many different columns with checkboxes & automatically input timestamp to a few columns when the checkbox is ticked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, timestamp, multiple-columns

I am quite bad at this stuff, I tried searching and have a somewhat workable script (apps script) but I just can't get it to work the way I want it to. I'm sure I added/edited things wrongly.

My Google sheet is a group work tracker and looks like the image below.
[image: Google Sheets image]

1. The primary need is to add an alert message when someone checks or unchecks any of the checkboxes in those columns (to prevent any misclicks - like so [image: Alert Msg]). We are using custom cell values for checked and unchecked as "1" and "0" respectively. The columns with checkboxes are F,K,P,R,S.
2. In addition to that, I would like a timestamp (format dd/mm/yyyy) to be populated 2 columns away when any of the checkboxes in columns F&K are checked (and confirms the alert message). However, when an already ticked checkbox is unticked, the date should not be removed or updated.

The below script works to a certain extent, but I don't know how to amend it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Video Projects' && e.range.columnStart==6,11,16,18 && e.value=='1') {
    var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Are you sure you want to tick this checkbox?', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if(resp==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
       var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getSheetName() == "Video Projects") {
    if(range.columnStart == 6) {
      var nextCell = range.offset(0, 2);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    } else if(range.columnStart == 11 && range.isChecked()) {
      var nextCell = range.offset(0, 2);
      nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
};
    }else{
      e.range.setValue("0");
    }
  }
```

If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be really helpful! :)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the relationship between your sample image and `checkboxes are F,K,P,R,S or in numbers 6,11,16,18,19`? And also, what is `numbers 6,11,16,18,19`? And, I cannot understand `That is to add a timestamp on columns H,M (or 8,13) when a checkbox in columns F,K is ticked and confirmed "Yes" when the alert comes.`.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and I think your English is great. :) 

I have re-uploaded an image with many columns visible. I hope the relationship is clearer now. The numbers were the column numbers as I have seen many people using them. 
What I need is basically all of the checkboxes to give a confirmation message when clicked on (this is to prevent any misclicks). In addition to that when any checkbox in Column F&G is ticked/checked a timestamp must be added two columns away.

Hope it makes sense! :)

Comment: Just protect the checkbox range.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check the checkboxes of the columns F,K,P,R,S.
- When the checkboxes of columns "F" and "K" are clicked, you want to put the date to the column "H" and "M", respectively.

#### Modification points:

- When `e.range.columnStart==6,11,16,18` is used as the if statement, all values of `e.range.columnStart` are `true`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

When this point is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const columns = [6, 11, 16, 18, 19]; // columns F,K,P,R,S
  const { range, value } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != 'Video Projects' || !columns.includes(range.columnStart) || value == "0") return;
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const res = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to tick this checkbox?', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (res == ui.Button.YES) {
    if (range.columnStart == 6 || (range.columnStart == 11 && value == "1")) {
      range.offset(0, 2).setValue(new Date());
    }
    return;
  }
  range.uncheck();
}
```

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

### Added 1:

About your following 2 new requests,

> Request 1: could we also add the alert message when unchecking a checkbox too?

> Request 2: Is it possible for it to input only the date as dd/mm/yyyy?

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const columns = [6, 11, 16, 18, 19]; // columns F,K,P,R,S
  const { range, value } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != 'Video Projects' || !columns.includes(range.columnStart)) return;
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const res = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to tick this checkbox?', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (res == ui.Button.YES) {
    if (range.columnStart == 6 || (range.columnStart == 11 && value == "1")) {
      range.offset(0, 2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }
    return;
  }
  range.uncheck();
}
```

### Added 2:

About your following a new request,

> Request 1: can be changed to "Are you sure you want to untick this checkbox?"

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const columns = [6, 11, 16, 18, 19]; // columns F,K,P,R,S
  const { range, value } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != 'Video Projects' || !columns.includes(range.columnStart)) return;
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if (value == "0") {
    const res = ui.alert("Are you sure you want to untick this checkbox?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (res == ui.Button.NO) range.check();
    return;
  }
  const res = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to tick this checkbox?', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (res == ui.Button.YES) {
    if (range.columnStart == 6 || (range.columnStart == 11 && value == "1")) {
      range.offset(0, 2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy"));
    }
    return;
  }
  range.uncheck();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment Tanaike. I've seen you help plenty of people here and appreciate your time! :) 
Yes you are right, the goals are correct and as I check/uncheck any box I'd like that confirmation message to pop. 

I pasted your entire script but not sure why nothing is happening. Would sharing the spreadsheet help? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FEpc5UkHhFgz64N8W2TTvufeIrEtO1pQ68zYtqtW5N0/edit?usp=sharing
I added few comments above the heading. Also, left a script that works somewhat well (but only for column 6 being checked only). Maybe it could help you. :)

Comment: @Mahe Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your sample Spreadsheet, I modified the sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Oh my, that works like a charm!! Thank you soo much, really! :')
Before I accept the answer as solved, if it is an easy thing to implement, could we also add the alert message when unchecking a checkbox too? As of now, it is only when checked we get to confirm. But when unchecking the date does not have to be removed or updated, simply a confirmation to uncheck too.

I will edit the original question too if it is possible for you to add that to the script too.
Thanks again! :D

Comment: @Mahe Thank you for replying. About your 2 new requests, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your 2 new requests, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike, you understood them correctly. There is a small thing that didn't work though, that is when I try to uncheck a ticked box and I click the "No" button when the message pops up, it still removes the tick from the checkbox. 
If you're going to amend that could we also change the alert message to "Are you sure you want to untick this checkbox?" only when unticking an already ticked checkbox.

Really appreciate your time! :)

Comment: @Mahe Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `when I try to uncheck a ticked box and I click the "No" button when the message pops up, it still removes the tick from the checkbox.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. This is what I meant,
Say there is a ticked checkbox at F8 (value "1" in my sheet), with the script proposed by you, when I try to untick that checkbox F8, I get the alert message "Are you sure you want to tick this checkbox?" and two buttons ("Yes" & "No"). When I click "No" it still unticks the checkbox at F8. Ideally, it should only untick the checkbox if I click "Yes". And if I click "No" the ticked checkbox should remain as it was. 
(Comment 1 of 2)

Comment: Also, it would be great if the alert message that pops up when trying to untick a ticked checkbox - can be changed to "Are you sure you want to untick this checkbox?"
(Comment 2 of 2) 
Cheers Tanaike! :)

Comment: @Mahe Thank you for replying. About your 3rd request, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your 3rd request, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly as intended. Thank you once again Tanaike for all the revisions. You are brilliant! :)

Comment: I noticed the slightest of flaws and I'm not sure why it is happening. Like my previous example say F8 checkbox is ticked. When I try to untick it, the alert message comes as intended, but if I press the "x" button ('cross button' or 'close button' on the top right) it still proceeds to untick that checkbox. Whereas it is actually supposed to reject it and remain as ticked. 
This is not the case when there is an unticked box and I try to tick it. Then when I close the popup (x button) it does not tick the checkbox but remains unticked. Any idea why that is happening? 
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: @Mahe About `but if I press the "x" button ('cross button' or 'close button' on the top right) it still proceeds to untick that checkbox.`, unfortunately, in the current stage, Google Apps Script cannot detect it. About your 4th question, I deeply apologize that I cannot have a clear solution. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for letting me know. Don't worry, you are very much skilful. Don't put yourself down Tanaike! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit() {

  var now = new Date()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var row = ss.getActiveRange().getRow() 

  ss.getRange(row, 1).setValue("value for first Col")
  ss.getRange(row, 2).setValue("value for second Col")
  ss.getRange(row, 3).setValue(now) //third Col with the current date/Time
}
```

The code above fires every time you edit any cell in the doc.
To prevent this you can add a if/else statement to check the Column like so.

```
  var col = ss.getActiveRange().getColumn()

  if (col == 2){//replace the 2 with the checkbox Column.
     //do this
  }
```

Now the Code fires every time you edit a cell in the second col and adds values to the same row.